# when I run my asp.net website and I try create file I have an error 'Access denied'

Tags: asp.net

my website does not create files and I set asp.net to write to directory.

Answer (score 3):

The account under which the website runs needs to have permissions to write files to the directory in which you want to write the files.

Answer (score 0):

it could be two things. this access denied error, is it a 403: Access Denied error? If so your IIS setup isn't configured for anonymous users. If its not it could be the IIS user the site is running as doesn't have permissions to access the site's folder.

Double check these two things, if it's neither we can look at what else is happening. Things I try is can I server a static file, or is it just ASP.NET etc

Answer (score 0):

Write access isn't enough to create files.  Try giving full control to the ASP.Net user (Network Service ny default) to the temporary files folder you are trying to write to.